# Dell XPS 13 2015 QHD black screen with linux

Tags: graphics, xps

On my **XPS 13 QHD** the laptop screen goes black after a couple of seconds (but this may vary) at the linux login window (The OS still works, only no screen), same thing happens with a linux live USB.

I can have the screen if I use an external monitor via mini display port. If I set `nomodeset` or `i915.modeset=0` in the grub kernel parameters the laptop screen works but the display port doesn't, so no external monitor and moreover graphics is poor.

I tried different kernels (from `3.19` to `4.2.0-040200rc3-generic`) and different distros (Fedora 22, Ubuntu 15.04), but I always have this issue.

Pre-installed Win8 works fine.

Any suggestion?

---

My PC specs:

- Dell XPS 13 (2015) 9343 QHD+
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
- Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (Intel HD Graphics 5500)

Comment: What's your BIOS version? You should have A05 at least. Try updating that.

Comment: My BIOS version is A05...

Comment: I have an XPS13 2015 QHD and i5, so pretty close to yours. I briefly had problems with 15.04 (last few weeks before upgrading to 15.10) but they were related to a regression in a kernel package, which is resolved in 15.10 (also, they won't be there on Fedora). No problems here. Laptop screen works fine, with or without an external monitor connected. Please let me know if you need more info about my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add

```
nvme
i915
```

to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules ? Don't forget about

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

afterwords.